# soem make all error

Tags: ros, orocos, ethercat

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed soem from this respiratory https://github.com/smits/soem .

When I run make all, It is showing error like this

--- Entering /home/coe/catkin_ws/src/soem/osal

--- Entering /home/coe/catkin_ws/src/soem/osal/linux

--- Create library libosal.a

--- Leaving /home/coe/catkin_ws/src/soem/osal/linux

--- Leaving /home/coe/catkin_ws/src/soem/osal

--- Entering /home/coe/catkin_ws/src/soem/oshw

--- Entering /home/coe/catkin_ws/src/soem/oshw/linux

--- Create library liboshw.a
--- Leaving /home/coe/catkin_ws/src/soem/oshw/linux

--- Leaving /home/coe/catkin_ws/src/soem/oshw

--- Entering /home/coe/catkin_ws/src/soem/soem

make[1]: *** No rule to make target `simple_test.o', needed by` simple_test'.  Stop.

make: *** [soem] Error 2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234341/soem-make-all-error/) by [Balaji](https://answers.ros.org/users/26502/balaji/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-05-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-05-14**:
Have you tried building with catkin_make instead of make? It looks like the build system for that package was converted to cmake, but the instructions weren't updated.

**Comment by [Balaji](https://answers.ros.org/users/26502/balaji/) on 2016-05-16**:
I placed that in the orocos folder. I build it with catkin_make_isolated --install. Now it is running nicely. How to run soem to scan slave devices?. The instruction in Internet is not working. How can i get tutorial for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you can get through this link it will get into any error.
https://github.com/OpenEtherCATsociety/SOEM

and finally you will need ros integrated soem. Here is the link for that :
https://github.com/gt-ros-pkg/ethercat-soem

---

Originally posted by [piyu23srma](https://answers.ros.org/users/27540/piyu23srma/) with karma: 66 on 2016-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0